# Old TV Show with a Floating Bed/Chair

Tags: tv, technology, story-identification

I remember an old TV show, probably early 80s??, and I remember this white room where the main character  would end the episode by laying down in like a floating bed/chair.  I think he actually floated above it with nothing below.  I believe it was a modern day setting and he was more of a tech wizard than anything else.  But I've had this image stuck in my head for years and I yet to come across something that fits.

Comment: In which country did you see this? What language? Was it live action?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214528/tv-show-starring-two-men-who-develop-various-gadgets (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason this triggered a memory of "The Wizard" from 1986.

http://www.thewizardtvfansite.com/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_(TV_series)

Comment: What about that show matches up with the details in the question?

Comment: The Wizard in the series was a genius inventor  (tech wizard). The floating bed just seems familiar to me and this was the first show I thought of. Unfortunately the series was not released on DVD so it's hard to verify.