# TV show starring two men who develop various gadgets

Tags: story-identification, tv

One is a regular size man and other is very short person. i think he is the one who invents the gadgets and the tall one uses them. I remember an episode in which tall man disguises his car ( by projecting a semi truck) to confuse the bad guys. It aired the same year as *Air Wolf*, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [*The Wizard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_(TV_series)) (1986). The title character, Simon McKay is a little person described as a *"philanthropist and innovative toymaker"*. He's assigned an (average-sized) CIA handler, Alex Jagger.

Together they fight crime and solve mysteries, [as you do](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=as%20you%20do).

Comment: Yes thats it.this show is way older thn i thought. i only remembers bits & pieces . but now i saw the clip its all coming back. cheers